# matplotlib.tri issues with neighbors

Tags: python, matplotlib, triangulation, surface, topology

I was wondering if anyone else has run into this problem? I'm trying to make triangulated surface and I would like to know what triangles are neighboring. Let's say, for example, I'm triangulating a torus, where I would create vertices in sets of rings. Then I would make a function

```
def torus(n, m):
    tri = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            a = j + i*m
            b = (j+1)%m + i*m
            c = (a+m)%(n*m)
            d = (b+m)%(n*m)
            tri += [[a,b,c], [b,c,d]]
    return  tri
```

that would create a set of triangles indicating their defining vertices. The trouble is when I use matplotlib to triangulate:

```
triangles = torus(n , m)
triang = matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), triangles)
```

my variable `triang`'s attribute `neighbors` isn't recording all the neighbors. On their site, it says it will return a

> -1 if there is no such neighboring triangle.

and I'm getting

```
>>> triangles[19]
[10, 29, 30]
>>> triangles[18]
[9, 10, 29]
>>> triangles[58]
[29, 30, 49]
>>> triangles[20]
[10, 11, 30]
>>> triang.neighbors[19]
array([18, 58, -1], dtype=int32)
```

and it's clear that `triangles[20]` is a neighbor of `triangles[19]` since the both share two vertices. Does anyone know of a workaround? Or what to do in this kind of situation? This isn't the only occurrence in my triangulation, there are actually many.